# anthill.exampletheme on Plone 4.2

Tags: plone

I'm trying to install a Plone skin called anthill.exampletheme 0.2 on Plone version 4.2 but it keeps returning the error below. The extension, anthill.skinner 0.8 installed and runs fine by itself but not the example theme. Please help!

```
Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
    Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
    Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
    Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 237, in _exec
    Module Products.CMFCore.FSPageTemplate, line 177, in pt_render
    Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
    Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
    Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 583, in do_setLocal_tal
    Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
    URL: file:c:\plone42\eggs\anthill.exampletheme-0.2-py2.6.egg\anthill\exampletheme\skins\anthill_exampletheme_custom_templates\main_template.pt
    Line 9, Column 0
    Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'language'>
    Names:

    {'container': <PloneSite at /test>,
     'context': <PloneSite at /test>,
     'default': <object object at 0x00991838>,
     'here': <PloneSite at /test>,
     'loop': {},
     'nothing': None,
     'options': {'args': ()},
     'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x08794A20>,
     'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/test/portal_skins/index_html>,
     'root': <Application at >,
     'template': <FSPageTemplate at /test/index_html>,
     'traverse_subpath': [],
     'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>}

    Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
    Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
    Module zope.tales.expressions, line 118, in _eval

KeyError: 'language'
```

Answer (score 3):

According to:

- https://dev.plone.org/ticket/10676

[anthill.exampletheme](https://pythonpackages.com/package/anthill.exampletheme)'s main_template is not Plone 4 compatible. Replace its main_template with a Plone 4 main_template (e.g. from sunburst) and you may get further.